# dust-me equilivant for js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, optimization

**Background:** I've recently found the great tool "Dust-Me Selectors" (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) - which allows me to remove all my unnecessary CSS styles that are not being used.

**Info:** I currently have 13x JS files that get minified and compressed - but are overall very bloated. I'd like to see if I can strip them down a bit, to help reduce my overall JS size.

**My question is:** Is there an equilivant of "Dust-Me Selectors" for Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Closure Compiler's advanced compilation can do somewhat that. Its not as simple as CSS, because of the complexity of the languages.

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

Other than that, there not really anything like Dust-Me for JS.